# chrome.storage.local.get limit

Tags: google-chrome-extension, limit

I'm creating a Google Chrome Extension that stores feed data.  I have my extension using unlimited storage and so far haven't hit any type of limits saving data, but I am running into one using chrome.storage.local.get!

If the total size returned by chrome.storage.local.get is > 840k the extension crashes.  I can't find any limit on this?!  Any ideas?  If I'm able to chrome.storage.local.set a value of 2MB why on earth wouldn't I be able to fetch it!!  I'm testing using Version 22.0.1229.94 m.

I've created a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159593) for the crash, but can anyone give me any information on this limit?

Answer (score 0):

It was a fluke.. A nice reboot fixed it.