# How can I retrieve lots of data in chrome.storage.local?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension that needs to store a lot of data. I've set the `unlimitedStorage` permission, and I'm successfully storing information using calls to `chrome.storage.local.set`. However, I'm unable to make calls to `chrome.storage.local.get`. When I make a call as simple as `chrome.storage.local.get(null, () => {})`, Chrome crashes.

My issue seems similar to [chrome.storage.local.get limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244598/chrome-storage-local-get-limit), except that that issue was about a much smaller amount of data, and turned out to be a fluke. When I call `chrome.storage.local.getBytesInUse(null, i => console.log(i))`, I get a result of `176031461`. (Admittedly, 180 MB is a lot more than Chrome extensions should typically use, but this extension will be running on my own machine.)

I'd like to be able to save all of this data into a JSON file, but to do that, it seems I need to bring it into memory first, and the only way to do that is through `chrome.storage.local.get`. I'm trying to use the method described at [Chrome Extension: Local Storage, how to export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160600/chrome-extension-local-storage-how-to-export) to download the data, but it doesn't even get to the callback function. I'm not sure what's causing it to crash, and I don't think it's a memory limit, given that I've followed the instructions at [Max memory usage of a chrome process (tab) & how do I increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491022/max-memory-usage-of-a-chrome-process-tab-how-do-i-increase-it) to increase Chrome's max memory to 4 GB.

One potential solution would be to set the first parameter to something other than `null` and download the data in chunks, but I'd rather not do that if I don't have to.

My questions are:

1. What is the limit to the amount of storage that can be retrieved this way?
2. Is there any way for me to get all of that data at once without crashing?
3. Is there a better way for me to be saving files from a Chrome extension?

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome which I've just reported (it's hidden currently though) which limits the amount of data to 128MiB since Chrome 60. You can use HTML5 FileSystem in Chrome or IndexedDB but I don't know if the bug also affect them.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, that's useful information. Clarification question: when you say it "limits the amount of data," you mean just for a single call to `chrome.storage.local.get`, correct? So if I saved a gigabyte of data but then downloaded it in chunks of 100 megabytes, that would work?

Comment: I didn't test it further.

Comment: The bug I reported was just fixed via https://crrev.com/c/1333989. Now the limit is that of the JS engine (a few GB, I guess). Normally it'll roll out in Chrome 72. I've asked them if it'll be merged in 71 (unlikely, though).

Comment: It's just been merged into Chrome 71 too, which becomes stable in December.